# How to gererate a `main.js` file of an angular library?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I build a `main.js` file from a library (inside the project folder of my angular v15 project)?

It always compiles this kind of folder sctrucutre.

[image]

But what I need is an entry `.js` file for importing it like this.

```js
const url = './assets/plugins/my-plugin/main.js'
const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
this.renderer.setAttribute(script, 'src', url);
this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, script);
```

Comment: why do you need `main.js`, any particular reason?

Comment: just updated the question.

Comment: Do you mean you want to compile your angular project in a single bundle?

Comment: no, just the library, so that i can import it at runtime as a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ng build` command for this issue.
https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: this i not working in this case